# Is there any way to manipulate (add, delete) certain keys and group all the value under one key?

Tags: python, json

is there a universal way to group the value to the same key in python

```
for i in data:
   val.append(i[value])
```

in python

```
[{'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': '5',
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2019'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': '5',
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2018'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': '5',
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2017'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': '5',
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2016'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': '5',
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2015'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': '5',
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2014'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2013'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2012'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2011'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2010'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2009'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2008'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2007'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2006'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2005'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'GB', 'value': 'United Kingdom'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2004'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': '4.4',
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2019'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': '4.4',
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2018'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': '4.4',
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2017'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': '4.4',
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2016'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': '4.4',
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2015'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': '4.4',
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2014'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2013'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2012'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2011'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2010'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2009'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2008'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2007'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2006'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2005'},
 {'indicator': {'id': 'PROT.MINOR.INV.EXT.OWNR.CONT.XD.0100.DB1519',
   'value': 'Protecting minority investors: Extent of ownership and control index (0-10) (DB15-19 methodology)'},
  'country': {'id': 'US', 'value': 'United States'},
  'value': None,
  'decimal': '1',
  'date': '2004'}]
```

1

Comment: Do you mean `i['value']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
val = [i['value'] for i in data]
```